# Bootstrap container and container-fluid on desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am running my web application using default bootstrap-sass on laptop with screen resolution - 1366 x 768.

- If I use container-fluid, the alert expands to fit screen width as expected
- Using container class is rendering a width of 728px.

As per my screen resolution, it should be using 1170px. Please let me know if my understanding is correct. I also have this meta tag in my `index.html`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

[image: Image showing the difference]

Comment: can you post code ?? what you are trying.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am using angular generator where it is overriding the default width for container inside header to be 730px and that is why the issue.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11647034)

Comment: I found that this is a issue with the code and not necessarily a question which I initially thought.

Answer (score 1):

If your screen width is `1366px` then the width of the `container` is fixed at `1140px` plus the `30px` (15px gutter each side). So the `container` total width is `1170px` at screens above `1200px`

It also might be helpful to add this meta tag instead

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To read more about this see:  http://getbootstrap.com/css/